# Select distinct rows, convert them into columns and count value

Tags: mysql, count, pivot, distinct

I have a problem with extracting data from one table.

I have a table, t_stat, as follows:

```
id, country, instId, date
 1, Belgium,      1, 2014-04-06  
 2, Germany,      2, 2013-05-07  
 3, Italy,        3, 2018-06-08
```

What I need as a result: i need to pick up every distinct country, and count how much installs it has on each date. It should look like this:

```
Date        Belgium  Germany Italy
2013-05-07  0        1       0
2014-04-06  1        0       0
2018-06-08  0        0       1
```

I know, result can be achieved with pivot, but I can not construct query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display, such as this, in application code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM( country = 'Belgium' ) AS Belgium,
    SUM( country = 'Germany' ) AS Germany,
    SUM( country = 'Italy' ) AS Italy
FROM t_stat
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: This would work perfectly, but I fotgot to add that I need dynamic pivot because country column will be editting all the time.